# Python threading number of arguments error

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

Pretty simple code:

```
import threading

def test(word):
    print(word)

threading.Thread(target = test, args = "hello").start()
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\phil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 950, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\phil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 888, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: test() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given
```

The 4 given arguments are the number of letters in the word "hello". This is what I don't understand, since the word "hello" is only one argument. If i replace "hello" with "A", it works, because "A" is only one letter.

Comment: Hmm, very odd, I thought that `"hello"` had 5 letters in it. Never mind. Did you mean: `args = ("hello",)`?

Comment: This works, thank you!
Indeed the word "hello" has 5 letters, I wrote the code with "test" instead, which has 4 letters, but replaced it with "hello" to not confuse you, because "test" is also the name of the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
import threading

def test(word):
    print(word)

threading.Thread(target=test, args=("hello",)).start()
```